# Find points outside a circle

Tags: c++, vector, geometry, points

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to find the points around a specific point on the circumference of the circle. I searched the website and found a question that does it for points on the inside of the circle.

I already created a circle and the points of that circle is stored in a vector, the cell. I have also created a vector of 20 points that are viruses. I also already created a function that will check one of the viruses hits the outside of the cell. I am trying to created a function in c++ that will check around the virus that hit the cell, to see if there are other viruses within a two point range in all directions of the virus. I want to count all of the viruses that are within that range and then move them into the circle at the same spot.

I am stuck on how to find the range. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to know how to find the distance between two points?

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code for finding circular viruses in range R:

```
Let r=distance between two circular viruses
Let R=range to be checked

if r is less than R, increment virus counter.

Finding r is easy:
r =   square root of( square of( x(virus 1)-x(virus 2) ) + square of( y(virus 1)-y(virus 2) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to store the data in a matrix.

E.G.:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

With 1 indicating that a "Virus" is at that position.

You could then create a recursive function to find the positions within 2 units of a virus-cell collision (the function would take a matrix as its parameter).